# Can you set iTunes to not sync your iPhone when it is connected? How do you disable sync?

Tags: itunes, iphone, sync

I sync my iPhone with my computer at home but I also connect it to my Macbook to do give it power sometimes. I do not want it to sync or start syncing at all. When I connect it the screen shows that it is starting to sync. I do not seem to run at least.

How can I disable syncing from this computer completely?